# How to use bitwise operators to return bits that have 0

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation

I've been struggling for quite a long time on this problem. This is a follow-up question on this answer ([How to divide x number of players into 2 teams randomly multiple times, differently every time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10861549/how-to-divide-x-number-of-players-into-2-teams-randomly-multiple-times-differen/10861679#10861679)).

So, I have x number of players, and for each I give `1 << n` mask value. By using those masks I can easily form a match with 2 players in each team. Now, if total number of players is 5, one possible match could be like this:

```
01100 team a
00011 team b
------------
10000 player resting
```

or with 6 players it could look like this:

```
100010 team a
001001 team b
-------------
000100 player resting
010000 player resting
```

**Question**
How can I get those resting players by comparing team a and team b masks together? (I'm a total bitwise noob so code examples are well appreciated)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do [XOR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xor) on value of team A and B:

```
var resting = a ^ b;
```

Then resting players will be marked by `0`, i.e:

```
100010 team a
001001 team b
-------------
101011 players resting
```

Finally, iterate through each bit of the result:

```
var totalPlayers = 6;

for (var i = 1; i <= totalPlayers; i++) {

   if ((resting & 1) === 0) {
       console.log("Player #" + i + " is resting.");
   }

   resting >>>= 1;
}
```

---

Here's live example: http://ideone.com/Kb3XJ (in Java, not JavaScript, but that's not the issue)

Comment: You're snippet works OK if the players resting are NOT the last bits. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/Mm4MM/1. Do you know the fix?

Comment: That's because `011011` is equal to `11011`. You'll have to store the total number of players in separate variable, and then change for-loop condition, from `resting != 0` to `i <= totalPlayers` - take a look at my edit. [JSFiddle live example](http://jsfiddle.net/Mm4MM/2/)

Comment: Cool, that was a simple fix I would have not see. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can bitwise OR them together then NOT it to get all the resting players.  You would then have to go bit by bit to get the separate resting players.

```
100010 
001001
------OR
101011 #all players playing
------NOT
010100 #all players not playing
```