# Combination generator improvements

Tags: javascript, optimization, bit-manipulation, combinations

Ok, some random dude at [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/14958/15086) asked me to pass this over here, so be it.

I have a combination generation code based on this answer: [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10861679/617822)

The basic idea is that I have a group of players (total of 6 - 14) and I need to form 2 teams each of having 3 players while the rest of the players are resting for that match. The code generates all the possible matches. The problem comes when I need to pick the next match setup randomly so that the players would only rest for, if possible, only 1 game. In addition, each teams should be as random as possible without having same players playing as a team as any previous game so far.

To clarify the problem this is a big no-no, that will happen if I just pick the next match from the array:

```
        Team 1 | Team 2 | Resting
Game 1: A B C    D E F    G H I J
Game 2: A B D    C E F    G H I J
Game 3: A B E    C D F    G H I J
```

... while this looks ok:

```
        Team 1 | Team 2 | Resting
Game 1: A B C    D E F    G H I J
Game 2: C G H    F I J    A B D E
Game 3: A D I    B E J    C F G H
```

I've modified the code so that now I have:

- players with bitmask
- teams with bitmask
- matches array with 2 teams and 1 resting group (each of them with bitmasks)

**Question**
Given that each of those match components, i.e. player, team and resting, have a mask value, how should I calculate the next game? With bitwise operators, how? Push every resting player into an array and exclude those from being resting next game. I've tried some multiarray thing which was a complete chaos and didn't end up well. So, I need some help with this. This is the first time I'm dealing with bitmasks.

**Code**

```
players: [],
teams: [],
matches: [],
Team: function () {
    this.list           = [];
    this.mask           = 0;
    this.count          = 0;
    this.full           = false;
    this.Add            = function (i) {
        this.list.push(GAME.players[i]);
        this.mask       |= GAME.players[i].mask;
        this.full       = ++this.count === 3;
    }
},

Resting: function () {
    this.list           = [];
    this.mask           = 0;
    this.count          = 0;
    this.full           = false;
    this.Add            = function (i) {
        this.list.push(GAME.players[i]);
        this.mask       |= GAME.players[i].mask;
        this.full       = ++this.count === (GAME.players.length - 2*3);
    }
},

addPlayers: function () {
    var indexes         = [],
        p,
        playersPerTeam  = 3,
        l               = playersPerTeam - 1;

    for (var p = 0; p < playersPerTeam; p += 1) {
        indexes[p] = p;
    }

    function addteam() {
        var team = new GAME.Team();

        for (var p = 0; p < playersPerTeam; p++) {
            team.Add(indexes[p]);
        }

        GAME.teams.push(team);
    }

    function addplayer(start, depth) {
        var target = GAME.players.length - playersPerTeam + depth + 1;

        for (var i = start; i < target; i++) {
            indexes[depth] = i;
            if (depth == l) {
                addteam();
            } else {
                addplayer(i + 1, depth + 1);
            }
        }
    }

    addplayer(0, 0);
}

// The code below runs during game initializing,
// before any round has started
var playerCount         = GAME.addedPlayers.length,
    i;

for (i = 0; i < playerCount; i += 1) {
    GAME.players[i] = {
        index: i,
        mask: 1 << i,
        name: GAME.addedPlayers[i].name
    };
}

GAME.addPlayers();

// The matches creation
for (var i = 0; i < GAME.teams.length; i++) {
    for (var j = i + 1; j < GAME.teams.length; j++) {
        var t1      = GAME.teams[i],
            t2      = GAME.teams[j],
            r1      = (GAME.players.length > 2*3) ? new GAME.Resting() : false;

        if ((t1.mask & t2.mask) === 0) { //this is where the masks come in
            if (r1) {
                var resting = t1.mask ^ t2.mask;

                for (var k = 0; k < GAME.players.length; k++) {
                    if ((resting & 1) === 0) {
                        r1.Add(k);
                    }
                    resting >>>= 1;
                }
            }

            GAME.matches.push({
                Team1: t1,
                Team2: t2,
                Resting: r1
            });
        }
    }
}

// The code below start a new round
// This should start a new randomly selected game described in my question
// and not like I'm doing it now
var gamesPlayed         = GAME.gamesPlayed,
    match               = GAME.matches[gamesPlayed];
```

Comment: Instead of re-asking, you should flag the codereview question for moderator attention, they could move it

Comment: Why do you think bit masks will help you here? Also, this will limit you to 32 players.

Comment: @Bergi OK, didn't know about flag the question to move it. 32 players limit isn't issue here since the total number of players will vary from 6 to 14. The above code works but my problem is how to iterate over matches array to get a decent next game so that there's enough variance on teams.